# Функция javascript вызывается по нажатию кнопки asp

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть функция, написанная на javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function imgchange1() {
        document.all.myimg.src = "images/myaccount/man.png";
    }
</script>
```

Есть серверная кнопка

После нажатия этой кнопки срабатывает функция imgchange1(). Как прописать в файле *aspx.cs вызов этой функции?

Answer (score 2):

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript: imgchange1()" />`

или

`Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "imgchange1()");`

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы функция imgchange1() срабатывала при загрузке страницы?

Comment: фу вещать хэндлеры в разметке.

Comment: @zb для ASP.NET WebForms это норма

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov ну это их проблемы.

Comment: @zb не вижу проблемы. Да, это устаревший подход к созданию веб-приложений. Но в рамках этого подхода разметка является самым правильным местом для хэндлера.